# Gatsby: creating multiple pages from JSON

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to use Gatsby to create multiple HTML pages from JSON data

I am trying to figure out how to work with `gatsby-node.js`

- `gatsby develop` → OK
- `gatsby build` → Fail

Here is my `gatsby-node.js` and it is broken

```
const path = require("path")

const quotesList = path.resolve("src/constants/quotesList")
const Quotes = path.resolve(`src/components/Quotes`)

exports.createPages = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  return new Promise(
    resolve => {
      resolve(
        quotesList.forEach(
          (quote, id) => {
            createPage(
              {
                path: `/quotes/${id}`,
                component: Quotes,
              },
            )
          },
        ),
      )
    },
  )
    .catch(
      e => console.error("Fail createPages", e),
    )
}
```

It ends up with

> WebpackError: Invariant Violation: Minified React error #61; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=61 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

How shouyld I change it to be able to load JSON data and generate multiple pages from it (about a hundred)?

Comment: Do you get this error when you run `gatsby develop` or only when you run `gatsby build`? It looks like it could actually be a problem with a React component rather than your `gatsby-node.js` file, but it will be more clear with the full (not minified) error messages you get with the development command.

Comment: @kennethormandy It is only for `gatsby build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at incorrect format for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop